# pingAll failed when using python API

Tags: python, sdn, mininet

```
mn --topo minimal --controller=remote,ip=192.168.95.136,port=6633 --mac --switch ovs,protocols=OpenFlow13 is OK
```

but something goes wrong with the following python code and always get

> Results: 100% dropped (0/2 received)

Python code:

```
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSKernelSwitch
net = Mininet(controller=RemoteController, switch=OVSKernelSwitch)
c1 = net.addController(controller=RemoteController, ip="192.168.95.136", port=6633)
h1 = net.addHost("h1", ip="10.0.0.1")
h2 = net.addHost("h2", ip="10.0.0.2")
s1 = net.addSwitch("s1")
s1.linkTo(h1)
s1.linkTo(h2)
s1.linkTo(c1)
net.start()
pingall()
net.pingAll()
```

What's wrong with my Python code?

Answer (score 0):

You refer below code :

```
def topology():

    "Create a network."
    net = Mininet( controller=RemoteController, link=TCLink, switch=OVSKernelSwitch, accessPoint=OVSKernelAP )

    print "*** Creating nodes"
    ap1 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap1', ssid="ssid_1", mode="g", channel="5" )
    ap2 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap2', ssid="ssid_2", mode="g", channel="11" )
    sta3 = net.addStation( 'sta3', ip="192.168.0.100/24", wlans=2 )
    h4 = net.addHost( 'h4', ip="192.168.0.1/24", mac="00:00:00:00:00:04" )
    s5 = net.addSwitch( 's5' )
    c0 = net.addController('c0', controller=RemoteController, ip='127.0.0.1', port=6653 )

    print "*** Configuring wifi nodes"
    net.configureWifiNodes()

    print "*** Adding Link"
    net.addLink(h4, s5, bw=1000)
    net.addLink(ap1, s5, bw=1000)
    net.addLink(ap2, s5, bw=1000)
    net.addLink(ap1, sta3)
    net.addLink(sta3, ap2)

    print "*** Starting network"
    net.build()
    c0.start()
    s5.start( [c0] )
    ap1.start( [c0] )
    ap2.start( [c0] )

    sta3.cmd("ifconfig sta3-wlan1 192.168.1.100/24 up")
    h4.cmd("ifconfig h4-eth0:0 192.168.1.1/24")

    print "*** Running CLI"
    CLI( net )

    print "*** Stopping network"
    net.stop()
```